# Visual Studio 2008 The project type is not supported by this installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solution given seem to have resolved my issue.

I am using visual studio 2008 professional addition. When I try open a project (.sln file) I get the below error:

'.csproj' cannot be opened. The project is not supported by this installation.

I understand it has some to do with the "GUIDS" on my csproj file which are below:

```
<ProjectGuid>{7C77DC9C-1EE5-4539-A12A-3F9F25813D8F}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

What do I do with this information? I has installed MVC's 1, 2 and 3 (scatter gunb approach) and have SP1 installed but still getting the same error. I ran devenv /setup in the command line, which didn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check what kind of project it is, is probably to install (Express) edition of VS2010 or VS2012, and open it there.

Maybe you can find out then if the project type is supported by VS2008 and if not, (manually?) edit the project to be able to load it, or create a new project in VS2008 and copy all relevant parts again in the newly created project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it must be something to do with a plugin I am missing rather than the project not being compatible as my colleague has no problem opening the same file in VS 2008.

Comment: In that case a reinstall of VS2008 would help (unless the plugin is an addon not in the default VS2008 package). You probably can see it rather easily on the project content at your colleague.

Comment: It is the guid for WAP, Web Application Model.  An add-on for VS2005.